# Not able to print out the results after the for-loop

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-imaging-library

I have the following code in Python:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        image = Image.open(root + '/' + file).convert('L')
        label = label_img(file)
        X.append(image)
        y.append(label)
        files.append(file)

print X
print y
print files
```

I however don't have any results returned, and the console where I run the program freezes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm running the program on 10 small images, so the output should be relatively fast. If I run some print statements in the loop for instance, the results just get in an instant.

Comment: Use `os.path.join()` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: How about some debugging? `print file`?

Comment: I neither see `X` nor `Y` nor `label_img(..)` in your code but I think they might be important somehow .... maybe you should brush up your code to a full  [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And why are you decomposing `files` then iterate over it and append the iter-variable back to it? that seems _ODD_

Comment: @Ryan I did "print file", and seemed to me that the program runs infinitely. Maybe that is the issue. But, why?

Comment: @Patrick Artner label_img() is just a function that returns a number.

Comment: Do you mean it's printing the same filename repeatedly?

Comment: @Simplicity: What did it print?

Comment: @Barmar It is going through all the files, say f1,f2,and f3. It prints them repeatedly.

Comment: `for file in files: ... files.append(file)` will probably never end...

Comment: @Ryan It is printing the files it is looping through repeatedly, and not necessarily in the same order.

Comment: Don't use the same `files` variable for iteration and appending.

Comment: @Barmar  you are right, I'm using it in the loop and for appending, which made the main issue

Answer (score 2):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):  # files is a list
    for file in files:                   # file is out of files
        image = Image.open(root + '/' + file).convert('L')
        label = label_img(file)
        X.append(image)
        y.append(label)
        files.append(file)               # here you append file to files
```

Your list of files is getting ever longer - no wonder it freezes...